# mysql updating last inserted id

Tags: mysql

I want to update a table by getting the last inserted id but it is giving no results.
here is the query :

```
 $quer = mysql_query("UPDATE date 
                      SET d_startdate = '$start', d_enddate = '$end' 
                      WHERE d_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() AND d_sid = $id");
```

d_id is the primary key and d_sid is a foreign key of another table

Comment: Is there a result when you make a select with: `WHERE d_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() AND d_sid = $id"` ?

Comment: do you mean you want to first insert the record in the same(date) table and just after that want to update date table with LAST_INSERT_ID ?

Comment: some dates has the same d_sid but each has a unique d_id. i want to update the date of the last inserted id that has d_sid

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID() is only available if you've done an INSERT during the same session, which apparently you didn't.

Comment: Can you  provide your full code

Comment: that is true i haven't done an insert before the update. thanks for that note

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used INSERT as well as UPDATE operation on my same table and its working fine. You can change this query as per your need.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_selectdb("test", $con);
$query = 'INSERT INTO item (`name`) VALUES ("DELTaaaA")';
$res = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
$query = 'UPDATE item set name="DELTaaaA1" WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()';
$res = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());
print_r($res);
?>
```

It should return 1 1

Comment: This is a php script to perform INSERT and UPDATE operation on database using LAST_INSERT_ID()

Comment: is there any other way to get last inserted id?

Comment: Yes, $id = mysql_insert_id(); can be used just after $res = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error()); (AFTER EXECUTING INSERT QUERY)

Comment: the thing is that i don't want to insert a new row.i want to update an existing row

Comment: above example assumes that you have inserted some record into database table and after that want to update same table's record. That's why i added INSERT query in the example. Otherwise LAST_INSERT_ID will simply return the most recent id generated into whole database.

Answer (score 0):

use code like this before that
`SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` and assign this to a variable, then use that variable in your code

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the normal syntax, but PDO syntax is quiet simple, you can get last inserted id by the function `PDO::lastInsertId()` use it as `$myPDOobject->lastInsertId()` . More information here : http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Answer (score 0):

`LAST_INSERT_ID` gives you the id of the *most recent* `insert`.

Suppose that you added a row which has `d_id=10` (`d_id` set by `auto increment`) and `d_sid=20` and then another one with `d_id=11` (again, `auto increment`) and `d_sid=30`.

You then want to look for the most recent insert with `d_sid=20`, but doing this with `LAST_INSERT_ID` is not possible, since `LAST_INSERT_ID` has value `11`, and no row matches with that `d_id` and `d_sid=20`. You have to keep track by yourself of the most recent `d_id` for each category, most likely when you insert the new rows.

- Do the `INSERT`
- `SELECT` the `LAST_INSERT_ID` (name it `L_ID`)
- Store the tuple `<d_sid, L_ID>` somewhere, so you know that for `d_sid` your most recent `INSERT` has value `L_ID`
- `UPDATE` your table where the `d_sid` is the one you want and `d_id` is taken from the tuple

As a side note, `mysql_*` is deprecated, so you should switch to something else like `mysqli` or `PDO`.