# Updating a row with query language, mysql, php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a basic question for you experts,

I want to update a row in mysql database by using the User_Id of an entry. I created User_Id as auto increment, primary key. Now for the last user I calculated its necessary variables, now I want to add that variable to the last user's necessary column through its User_id.

The name of the variable I want to add is $improvement. I wrote the code below, however I dont now how to do that depending on its User_Id.

```
$sql = "
UPDATE users 
SET Improvement='$improvement'
WHERE ... )
";  

mysql_query($sql, $accounts);
```

I dont know what to write to the "..." part in the code. Please give me feedback if you see a problem in my question. I can give my table if you need.

Comment: Use a `SELECT` query to fetch the latest `Improvement` value `WHERE User_id = '$userid'`, then assign to `$improvement = $latestimprovement." ".$improvement;`

Comment: I want to update the last user, so I want to do it the highest User_Id, In other words last user entry.

Comment: So you want to change the `User_id` of that row? On who updated that row?

Comment: I want to change Improvement column, I want to change the last user's Improvement column

Comment: Bro my syntax wasnt right, As I answered in the question what should be the correct syntax @Logan Wayne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mysql updating last inserted id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192756/mysql-updating-last-inserted-id)

I guess I found the answer in that link:

```
$sql = "
UPDATE users 
SET Improvement='$improvement'
WHERE User_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() )
";
```

However I am not sure if "SET Improvement='$improvement'" part is the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

If your user_id is primary index then you can use

$sql = "
UPDATE users 
SET Improvement='$improvement'
order by user_id DESC limit 1 )
";

mysql_query($sql, $accounts);

Comment: I think You want to update your last inserted user's details?
This may be help you to update last user detail

Comment: do you think the Improvement='$improvement'  is right syntax for this?

Comment: This is not a issue you can use it. Improvement='$improvement'
but if you use Improvement='".$improvement."' here it will be fine.
Ronnie plz mail me on jbr.rahul@gmail.com